# Can i choose div class from javascript value

Tags: javascript, html

```
$(function() {
window.addEventListener('message', function(event){
$('.health').html(event.data.health);
}); 
});


<div class= ??? > -- if i want use the $('.health').html(event.data.health);  how to do it
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/medical-health/256/heart-beat-2-icon.png" alt="" class="avatar"/>
</div>
```

$('.health').html(event.data.health); = is the name div class

div class if i want use the  $('.health').html(event.data.health); how to do it

Comment: The "." in the selector means that you are selecting by class. So the class needs to be "health". See: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: You need a selector for this <div class= ??? > either an ID or another class, <div class= 'target' >  so you can use this $('.target').addClass('health');   , if you use $('div') all div will be targeted